# Onsubmit event silently killed by onchange

Tags: javascript, events, browser, dom-events

Onsubmit event can silently kill onchange event, if called simultaneously. I assume race condition in js engine. Tested in chrome, FF3, FF6 and IE9.

To reproduce you need to change contents of input and click on submit button. Do not make any additional clicks between input change and submit button click.

```
<div id="somediv">
    <div>one</div>
    <div>two</div>
</div>
<form method="POST" id="someform">
    <input type="text" name="input1" id="someinput" value="change me" />         
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('someinput').onchange = function() {
        //some delay - DOM operations, AJAX or alert:
        document.getElementById('somediv').getElementsByTagName('div')[1].style.display = 'none';
        //or alert('123');
    }
    document.getElementById('someform').onsubmit = function() {
        alert('This event is not called');
    }
</script>
```

Expected behavior: onchange event, than onsubmit.

If we use button instead of submit and call events one after another - everything works as expected.

If there is no operations (no delay) in onchange event - works as expected.

If onchange will change div's color (not display) - **sometimes** (3/10) works as expected, lol.

js-guru, please, explain, what the hell is going on?

Comment: It's not a race condition. Aside from web workers, JavaScript is executed in a single thread in every single browser.

Comment: Ok, let it be so. But what is it than?

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce it in Chrome on Ubuntu - no luck (tried it dozen of times). Every time both callbacks are fired. Could it be something OS specific?

Comment: Tried in Chrome 15.0.874.120 on Ubuntu 10 a minute ago: form is not submited. Are you shure, that you reproduce it properly? You should click "submit" right after changing "input".

Comment: Created a jsFiddle for seeing this strange behavior in action: https://jsfiddle.net/amwebexpert/Lmdp6bp7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`onsubmit` works like `onclick`, which requires `onmousedown` and `onmouseup` events consecutively. If your code shows a dialog (eg. alert) or replaces the button after `onmouseown` event, consequent `onmouseup` is not fired and thus cancels the event. Swapping the textbox and button with somediv should help.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I don't show alert ot replace submit button in my code. I just hide one div (no forms or buttons inside that div).

Comment: As for alert, it was an example. On the other hand hiding "somediv" moves the button upwards. Have you tried swapping their places.

Comment: Checked out code with onmousedown and onclick - you are right. Thank you, that was very mystifying issue!

Answer (score 3):

Note that there has been problems with JS engine not running the submit when a dialog box is open: [Javascript onchange event preventing onsubmit event in HTML form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489527/javascript-onchange-event-preventing-onsubmit-event-in-html-form/493240#493240)

> It turns out that it is only presence of an alert() - or a confirm() -
>   during the input's onchange event that causes the form's onsubmit
>   event to not fire. The JS thread appears to get blocked by the
>   alert(). The workaround is to not include any alert() or confirm() in
>   the input's onchange call.

It's likely that they worked around that bug by disallowing alert() or confirm() commands in the onchange call to allow the form to submit as expected.

Comment: I've already read that post. You can replace "alert" in my code with some other "delay". E.g. some DOM operation.

Comment: Removed "alert" from my code. Now only DOM operation. Event still disappears.

Comment: On Chrome/OSX if I modify the HTML to stop the submit button from shifting locations (move the div beneath the form), the code works every time.  Commenting back in the alert, however, returns to your original complaint - only the onchange fires.

Comment: Thinking more about it, it's a reasonable result.  If there were an alert on an onchange, as a user I would probably not want the form submitted as the alert is probably telling me of an issue.  The user can dismiss the alert and immediately click the submit button again.

Comment: Sorry, don't understand your comment about stopping the submit button shifting locations. What about my new code? Works ok in Chrome/OSX?

Comment: In the above code, the onchange event is removing one of the divs and on Chrome/OSX it causes the Submit button to change location; it shifts up the page.  When that happens it seems to drop the onsubmit.  However, when I changed the html around to place the div data beneath the form, the onchange no longer moved the submit button and it behaved better - it worked expected and triggered both events every time.  After commenting back in alert('123'), it went back to only running the onchange.

Comment: Ian, thank you for testing! However, the bug becomes more weird.

Comment: Ian - are you sure that it "drops on submit"? I get the shiffting part  - it's the same on Ubuntu, but when I click submit button that's been shifted onsubmit callback is fired.

Comment: I should have said that it usually drops the onsubmit.  It did fire a few times.